# Decision trees: Measure of split quality which takes into account rare values

Tags: regularization, cart, pruning

I am working on a classification problem in which the positive class is very rare.
The dataset consists of categorical variables, as shown in the example below.
The variables are hierarchical, in the sense that the values which *var_i* may take depends on the the value of *var_i-1*. In the mock data below, for instance, *var_1* can be *l* or *r* when *var_0* is *a*, or *u* or *d* when *var_0* is *b*.

| var_0 | var_1 | var_2 | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | l | x | 0 |
| a | r | x | 0 |
| a | l | z | 0 |
| b | u | p | 0 |
| b | d | q | 0 |
| b | d | w | 1 |

The variables thus may be thought of as a tree, as visualized below.

```
                   ·
                  / \ 
                 /   \ 
                /     \ 
               /       \ 
              /         \ 
var_0        a           b
            / \         / \
           /   \       /   \
var_1     l     r     u     d   
         / \   / \   / \   / \  
var_2   x   y x   y p   q q   w
```

I suspect that some of the 'splits' in this tree do not convey any information about my target variable. For example, the split from *a* into *l* and *r* might be redundant, and I could reduce the number of leaf nodes by pruning the tree, resulting in the tree shown below.

```
                   ·
                  / \ 
                 /   \ 
                /     \ 
               /       \ 
              /         \ 
             a           b
            / \         / \
           /   \       /   \
          x     y     u     d   
                     / \   / \  
                    p   q q   w
```

My first idea for this was to use existing heuristics for pruning decision trees, specifically Gini impurity or information gain.
However, the positive class in my data is very rare, and the tree will therefore contain nodes with very few, or zero, positives. As I understand, a split resulting in nodes with only negative classes will have a high purity, and will thus be retained by a pruning procedure which uses e.g. Gini impurity as a heuristic.
I would like a heuristic which doesn't consider a split 'good' simply if it results in a completely pure node, but also requires that the number of data points in the node is relatively high.

- Am I correct that unbalanced datasets are a problem to using Gini impurity for pruning?
- If so, what is a good alternative?

Comment: When the positive class is very rare, maybe some variant of logistic regression would work better?

Comment: The pruning procedure I'm asking about isn't the final classifier. It is meant to be a preprocessing step to lower the dimensionality of a text feature.